# After a few days, the Java application stops working

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am writing a pet application in Java. Spring database Web.
I place all this on the server in separate docker containers.
The database is created in the docker-compose file

```
  postgres-content:
    image: postgres:14.1
    container_name: content_db-v01
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5532:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*****
    volumes:
      - /home/my-db/content_db:/var/first-prj/data/content
      - ./sql/create_db_catalog.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_db_catalog.sql
```

I use liquibase to create a table. To work with the JPA database.

```
spring:
  jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation: true
  jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: always    
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres-content:5432/catalog_content?currentSchema=catalog&stringtype=unspecified
    username: content
    password: *****
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog.xml
```

Everything works fine. I launch it, I check what I wrote for a day or two. But a few days pass, I connect to the server to download a new version. And my application is constantly overloaded.
Just restarting containers doesn't help.
I'm deleting the directory from the database on the server. I overload and everything works again.
The first time I thought it was an accident. But this happened the second time.

Tell me where and how to find a solution to this problem?
Where to look?
Here's what he writes in the logs:

```
19-01-2022 07:41:33.921 [main] INFO  ru.home.marketplace.contentservice.ContentServiceApplication.logStarting - Starting ContentServiceApplication v1.0-SNAPSHOT using Java 14.0.2 on c8abc4b4ef14 with PID 1 (/content.jar started by root in /)
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:33.926 [main] INFO  ru.home.marketplace.contentservice.ContentServiceApplication.logStartupProfileInfo - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:35.696 [main] INFO  org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:35.872 [main] INFO  org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 156 ms. Found 7 JPA repository interfaces.
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:36.710 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9005 (http)
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:36.730 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.log - Starting service [Tomcat]
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:36.730 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.log - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.54]
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:36.820 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/content].log - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:36.820 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.prepareWebApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2785 ms
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:37.014 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:38.138 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
content-v01         | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
content-v01         |   at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:313)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318)
content-v01         |   at ru.home.marketplace.contentservice.ContentServiceApplication.main(ContentServiceApplication.java:11)
content-v01         |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
content-v01         |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
content-v01         |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
content-v01         |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
content-v01         | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-content
content-v01         |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567)
content-v01         |   at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
content-v01         |   at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
content-v01         |   ... 41 common frames omitted
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:38.140 [main] WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:38.146 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.log - Stopping service [Tomcat]
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:38.162 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.logMessage -
content-v01         |
content-v01         | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:38.184 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
content-v01         | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318)
content-v01         |   at ru.home.marketplace.contentservice.ContentServiceApplication.main(ContentServiceApplication.java:11)
content-v01         |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
content-v01         |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
content-v01         |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
content-v01         |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
content-v01         | Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
content-v01         |   at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:318)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
content-v01         |   ... 27 common frames omitted
content-v01         | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
content-v01         |   at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:313)
content-v01         |   ... 29 common frames omitted
content-v01         | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-content
content-v01         |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567)
content-v01         |   at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
content-v01         |   at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
content-v01         |   ... 41 common frames omitted
content-v01 exited with code 1
```

The database container is unavailable. But why did this happen? And where to look for the error?
Here are the logs of the container with the database after restarting the container. I didn't think to look before restarting.

```
2022-01-19 07:39:17.471 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-01-19 07:39:17.473 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-01-19 07:39:17.473 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-01-19 07:39:17.600 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-01-19 07:39:17.681 UTC [64] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-01-19 07:39:17 UTC
2022-01-19 07:39:17.721 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-01-19 07:42:00.441 UTC [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2022-01-19 07:42:00.446 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2022-01-19 07:42:00.450 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 70) exited with exit code 1
2022-01-19 07:42:00.454 UTC [65] LOG:  shutting down
2022-01-19 07:42:00.546 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to show some, any, debugging effort?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to show some effort

Comment: the problem is that I do not know where to look. How to catch this error? Something is happening with the database. Why it works for several days, and then an error occurs. And at this time, no one works with her.

Comment: after checking the log, i think the cuase was directly caused by networking issue, and the code doesn't do enough try catch to handle such case.

Comment: But can a network problem lead to the destruction of the database?

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed. Seems it's a connection error, can you check via your SQL manager tool if it connects?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running it using the same network?

Add your network to your services named `postgres-content` and `spring`.

```
networks:
  - app-network
```

Finally, create your network definition at the bottom of your `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
networks:
  app-network:
    name: app-network
```